# Synergy with Rage / Ranger’s Focus / Overhand Chop

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, class-feature, multi-classing

I have this multi-class warrior: Superstitious Barbarian, Guide Ranger, and Two-Handed Fighter.

Can I effectively combine Rage, Ranger’s Focus, and Overhand Chop into one fabulous attack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

Both [Ranger's Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo-ranger-archetypes/guide/) and [Rage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Barbarian/#TOC-Rage-Ex-) are ongoing effects, and add different bonuses to your character.

The [Overhand Chop](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/two-handed-fighter/) ability will apply on any single attack, and can definitely be used with any other effects in place.

If using Overhand Chop, you may also find the [Vital Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vital-strike-combat-final/) line of feats useful, as these will also apply on the single attack action, and further increase your damage.

Comment: Might be worth adjusting that last line. Increasing strength, whilst understood to mean the power of the attack in question, generally has connotations of increasing or applying more of the Strength ability score - which Vital Strike does not apply any further benefit from.